# Analysis of Tarrega's Serenata Espanola

Tags: harmony

I am an amateur and try to explore the arrangement of the past Masters. Great forum. I learn a lot from all of you. Thanks you.

At MEASURE 10, the chord should be E major as the key of the piece is A minor. I do not understand why G is not sharpened. ? modulation to C major Sheet music of SE Tarrega
[image]

Regards, Thien

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather common occurrence in "classical" music (and spills over into other genres.) In a minor key, the sixth and seventh scale steps are mutable; they occur in both lower and upper "tones." (I haven't found a good phraseology; sharp and flat aren't accurate and can be confusing.) The seventh step is often raised at cadence points (as mentioned in the question.) However, measure 10 isn't part of a phrase-ending cadence so using the "lower" form (G rather than G#) is a possibility. There is no "rule," just the composer's "ear."

This use of the lower version of step 7 (I really need a word for this.) often occurs when there is a repeated section; the first time through, the lower form is used, and the second time, the upper version. The idea is to add some contrast to emphasize the cadence.

Comment: "Raised" and "Lowered" are the terms of art.

Comment: We can also refer to the lowered 7 as the "subtonic" as opposed to the raised "leading tone."

Answer (score 2):

In key A minor, there are a couple of 'extra' notes which are often used. Funny, we're often asked why there **is** a G♯, when it doesn't appear in the *natural* minor scale.

In key A minor, the notes most used are A B C D E F F♯ G and G♯. the two sharpened notes belong to the classical *melodic* minor scale, ascending, which reverts to the natural minor notes when descending. I'll not go into reasons why here - they've been covered several times for different questions.

So, the writer wanted to (and could if he wanted, without compunction or fear of 'breaking any rules') use either, or here, actually both. He obviously preferred the sound that way! And to that end, wrote a couple of G♮s prior, in the same bar, before 'sweetening' it up with a G♯, which does, usually, lead better to the A in the next. There's a reason it's called the 'leading note'...

Answer (score 1):

Measure 9 notably has an A flat in its Beat 3. G sharps in Measure 10 would provide no contrast with it.

I completely agree with your "modulation to C major" analysis - ignoring inner passing notes, Measures 10-11 pull off a I6/4 - V7 - I6/4 - V cadence portion in C major, while (ignoring non-chord tones) Measure 12 is I in C major. This means that Measure 10 uses an incomplete C/G chord, so it needs G natural instead of G sharp.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Minor key can be natural ( with no added sharps), harmonic( raised 7th) or melodic ( raised 6th and 7 th note going up Eg #F-> #G -> A going up and natural F and G going down Eg G-> F-> E.
As I understand, bA in measure 9 is a passing note( A-> bA->G). It proceeds to G.

In measure 10, the chord is Eminor with G-> #G-> A. If it is a modulation to C , I cannot see G chord preceding the C chord. It is very hard to understand. From what I understand, in A minor , if G proceeds to A, it needs to be sharpened.

Comment: In measure 10, I think both #G and A are passing note as they proceed to B ( which is part of the E minor chord). The upper E proceeds to F( upper note) then return to E . The next chord is C. If it is a modulation to C or secondary dominant, there should be a G chord preceding the C chord.

Comment: At least to me, Beat 3 of Measure 9 sounds overwhelmingly like an Ab chord, thus making Measure 10 sound a lot more convincingly like an incomplete I6/4-of-C-major chord, as bVI-I6/4 (both of III) is a ton more common than bVI-iii6 (both of III) or #VII-v6 (both of i this time).

Comment: Thanks very much all the contributors. I learn so much from this forum.